# Flutter how to create a zip file

Tags: flutter

How to create a zip file with Flutter? I tried with archive package but it does not have any sample to create a zip file. Please help. I am totally new in Flutter. After creating the zip file with archive package error getting while extracting the zip file.

With archive package this is what I did:

```
  void _generateItemArchive(ZipFileEncoder encoder, int id) async {
List<Item> _itemList = await DBProvider.db.getAllItem(id);
_itemList.forEach((Item _item) {
  encoder.addFile(File(_item.photo));
});
```

}

```
ZipFileEncoder encoder = ZipFileEncoder();
encoder.create(join(documentsDirectory.path, 'product.zip'));

encoder.addFile(File('${documentsDirectory.path}/TestDB.db'));

List<Supplier> _supplierList = await DBProvider.db.getAllSupplier();
_supplierList.forEach((Supplier _supplier) {
  encoder.addFile(File(_supplier.photo));
  _generateItemArchive(encoder, _supplier.id);
});
```

I am getting an error when I tried to call encoder.close(); I need to add the files from database record.

Comment: Check out the [example tab](https://pub.dev/packages/archive#-example-tab-) There is a convenience method to zip a whole folder, or you can zip individual files, or zip bytes in memory. Edit the question to make it more precise once you've tried the examples. (You can also just try a standalone Dart app to practice.)

Answer (score 9):

Add this in your 'pubspec.yaml' file (from https://pub.dev/packages/archive)

```
archive: ^3.1.6
```

Import this in your dart file:

```
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
```

Finally:

```
Directory appDocDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
var encoder = ZipFileEncoder();
encoder.create(appDocDirectory.path+"/"+'jay.zip');
encoder.addFile(File(selectedAdharFile));
encoder.addFile(File(selectedIncomeFile));
encoder.close();
```

Comment: Is this supported in flutter web?

Comment: yes, the latest version of dependencies 'archive: ^2.0.13' is now supporting on web also

Comment: addFile returns a Future. Is it safe to call it this way without await ?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a new plugin optimized for Android and iOS available [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_archive) (this is my library). Sample for zipping files:

```
  final sourceDir = Directory("source_dir");
  final files = [
    File(sourceDir.path + "/file1"),
    File(sourceDir.path + "/file2")
  ];
  final zipFile = File("zip_file_path");
  try {
    FlutterArchive.zipFiles(
        sourceDir: sourceDir, files: files, zipFile: zipFile);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```